# Reference for Connes Bourbaki membership or otherwise

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, noncommutative-geometry, bourbaki

Alain Connes being a leading French mathematician today one could ask whether he is a member of the Bourbaki group. Is there a published reference that would either refute or confirm this?

Comment: This is not good question in MO, try to ask this question in other stack

Comment: This is stated in Wikipedia, but that could hardly count as a reference :)

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, At wiki there is indeed a reference to a book by Mashaal where under the "Serre" entry he mentions that Connes (b. 1947) is (was?) a member. If you post this as an *answer* I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that it's worth it (posting this as an answer) :)

Comment: I vote to reopen as I cannot see why it would be off-topic, and nobody gave a reason why it would be off-topic. It simply asks about a reference for a historical fact and history of math is on-topic; and *past* Bourbaki membership is also not kept private AFAIK, so in contrast to some other recent question there is not even this problem, and in any case it asks for a reference.

Comment: Better suited for [HSMSE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: In France, it is not known Connes was or not a Bourbaki's member. No intrest for anybody !

Comment: @Al-Amrani, do you feel that Connes' notion of *Primordial Mathematical Reality* as Bourbaki roots?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Connes was a member, according to M. Mashaal  "Bourbaki: A secret society of mathematicians", AMS 2006 (translated from the French by A. Pierrehumbert). It says so on page 18; see the [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=-CXn6y_1nJ8C&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false). But, as was also mentioned there, there is a rule that members retire at age 50, so by that rule he is no longer a member.

Answer (score 6):

Let's hear from Connes himself. This video (in french, sorry) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqR459KxDVU&t=36s  (featuring Serre, Dixmier, Cartier, and Connes) explains the the genesis of Bourbaki (over a +70-year period!), with an accent on membership and the historical circumstances around the recruitment of certain notable members (e.g Serre, Borel, Grothendieck). You'll also find details about the recruitment of Alain Connes (the interviewer), though this is not the focus of the conversation.

Comment: Great video! The discussion features only Connes and Serre, and I couldn't find details about Connes's Bourbaki membership.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Good catch. Indeed The video I linked was mistakenly a video in which Connes interviews Serre on the Serre-Grothendieck correspondences. I've corrected the link to the one on the interview by Connes, of Serre, Dixmier, and Cartier about Bourbaki.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault  Not related to the question, but If you liked those videos, then this one might also be interesting to you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lm77dq0kXGc. It's a Cartier on *prehistoric* Grothendieck, or how he *murdered* functional analysis https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lm77dq0kXGc